# Getting the date out of a CalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I'm desiging a simple android activity with an EditText, a CalendarView and a Button. Pressing the button suppose to send back the user entered text and selected date (one day only) in a YYYY/mm/dd format.

First I thought there will a very simple way to solve this eg:

```
str_selectedDay = myCalendarview.getYear() + "/";
str_selectedDay += myCalendarview.getMonth() + "/";
str_selectedDay += myCalendarview.getYear();
```

but actually there are no methods like these exist for the CalendarView. The only method remotely similar is the `myCalendarView.getDate()`. The problem with this is it returns the date of today in millis and not what the user has selected.

I googled the problem (found handful of old questions here as well) and some people suggested to use something like this:

```
myCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            str_seletedDate = String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);

        }
    });
```

A major problem with this is that if the user just want to select the current day (so what is selected by default) that means he doesnt tap on the CalendarView therefore the `str_bookDueDate` variable wont get updated ever.

So I have came up with this solution:

```
myCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        try {
            String str_selectedDate= String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
            Date date = sdf.parse(str_selectedDate);
            long millis = date.getTime();
            myCalendarView.setDate(millis);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            UImessage.Log(e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

And then when I need to get the date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date(myCalendarView.getDate()));
```

So whats happening that when the user selects a new day in the calendarview I have to change the Date of the calendarview to what he selected by converting the selected year, month and date back to millis and write it with the setDate() method.

This works but seems 100% convoluted and unintuitve.

My questions is: what is the RIGHT way to get the information from the CalendarView?

Comment: I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031314/how-can-i-get-selected-date-in-calenderview-in-android) thread might answer your question

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't . The most upvoted answer has the issue I have described by not updating the date string if the user actually just wants to keep the current date. In this case the OnDateChangeListener will never be called.